# Organizing a JSON into some text boxes in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to 'de-serialize'? a json returned from an API in vb.net 
Here is the JSON from the api's link: http://yugiohprices.com/api/rising_and_falling

Here is the code I currently have that just grabs the JSON:

```
    Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://yugiohprices.com/api/rising_and_falling"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "GET"

    request.ContentLength = 0
    Dim responseContent As String
    Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Id like to get a result that is similar to the following:
textbox_rising Content: 
(name: ...
price: ...
priceshift: ... '(must be positive)
cardnumber: ...
cardset: ...
rarity: ...)
(name: ...
price: ...
priceshift: ... '(must be positive)
cardnumber: ...
cardset: ...
rarity: ...) and so on...

textbox_falling Content: 
(name: ...
price: ...
priceshift: ... '(must be negative)
cardnumber: ...
cardset: ...
rarity: ...)
(name: ...
price: ...
priceshift: ... '(must be negative)
cardnumber: ...
cardset: ...
rarity: ...) and so on...

I hope you can understand what I mean, i'm not very familiar with JSON and am quite new to vb in general, thanks in advance.

Edit:...
classes added:

```
Public Class Rising
Public Property name As String
Public Property price As Double
Public Property price_shift As Double
Public Property card_number As String
Public Property card_set As String
Public Property rarity As String
End Class

Public Class Falling
Public Property name As String
Public Property price As Double
Public Property price_shift As Double
Public Property card_number As String
Public Property card_set As String
Public Property rarity As String
End Class

Public Class Data
Public Property rising As Rising()
Public Property falling As Falling()
End Class

Public Class rfJSON
Public Property status As String
Public Property data As Data
End Class
```

Code added:

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of rfJSON)(responseContent)
txt_rising.Text = obj.ToString
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill check it out, I did google a few things but most of what I found was confusing.

Comment: OK well I have created classes and written a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject string and my output is just: 'projectname'.'classname'

Comment: I have made an edit to show what I have added.

Comment: 'name is not a member of rising', Am i stupid? xd

Comment: I was putting: obj.data.rising.name.item(1).ToString aha, thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way I can commend you? I'm new to this site.

Comment: I am already condemned